# Request for data that generates chart always empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data that generates a chart on a website using python's request module.

My code currently looks like this:

```py
# load modules
import os
import json
import requests as r

# url to send the call to
postURL = <insert website>

# utiliz get to pull cookie data
cookie_intel = r.get(postURL, verify = False)

# get cookies
search_cookies = cookie_intel.cookies

#### Request Information ####

# API request data
post_data = <insert request json>

# header information
headers = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

# results 
results_post = r.post(postURL, data = post_data, cookies = search_cookies, headers = headers, verify = False)

# result
print(results_post.json())
```

As a quick summary, I first loaded the site to then inspect it, from there I identified the url for the request in the network tab and then checked the required request data in the payload tab. Then I took the user-agent from the request headers tab.

The request itself works, however, it is always empty. I have tried altering all sorts of inputs but without success. I would highly appreciate any sort of tips that would help me to solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in this case you have to use `json=` instead of `data=` when making the post request according to the requests [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) . By replacing this part of your code you should get the expected response.

```
results_post = r.post(postURL, json = post_data, cookies = search_cookies, headers = headers, verify = False)
```

You can also try other scraping tools like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) to crawl these data and maybe running the crawler on the cloud using [estela](https://estela.bitmaker.la/docs/).